# What is the deal about ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone

My husband is an ubuntu believer.  Can someone please explain to me what he sees in it, I can't figure it out, especially the ubuntu one.

Also, we use ubuntu one but can only make one iphone file for pictures.  Anyway to put folders for both of us?

Comment: seriously, he's the only one who can answer your question

Comment: I'm closing this because its not really suited for our question and answer format. For your first question about your husband, as the answers below all say the only person who can answer that is him. If you can ask another question about the Ubuntu One part, that'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you read this satirical piece, and then ask him.

http://blog.josephliau.com/ubuntu-grievous-goat/

<sub>seriously, he's the only one who can answer your question</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Sarah, Linux users (Ubuntu users included) are a tough breed to marry, bless you for that.  Everyone has different reasons for using Ubuntu.  Many of the reasons people choose to use Ubuntu are ethical, many are just about doing what you want with your computer.  Because Ubuntu is open source, it allows more customization than a Windows or Mac computer.  That being said, it does sometimes make it more difficult for users not accustom to that freedom, or to the feel of an Ubuntu Linux system.  It would be possible for him to create an account for you on the computer where it looked and felt like Windows of Mac (hope I'm not getting him in over his head here), and that may make the experience more enjoyable for you.

Generally it's preferred to have a single question per posting here at Ask Ubuntu, but as to the second part of your question.  Once you have your own account on the computer you should be able to set up your own Ubuntu One account with your own pictures.  If you'd prefer you could use Dropbox instead.  If you'd prefer to have a seperate pictures directory in Ubuntu One without your own computer account you just have to have a seperate directory (all things your husband should be able to set up if you don't feel comfortable with).

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Ubuntu for 4-5 yr s now and some of the big reasons I like it so much is that:

it is a lot faster on my machine

it uses less resources for most things (you don't have so much running in the background needlessly)

It doesn't slow suffer from registry bloat like windows (slow down over time)
 and is more reliable than windows (it doesn't crash near as much).

How ever on your second question I'm not sure as I only use Ubuntu One to sync my address books and firmware files for different hardware on my machines.